# Bubble-sort in C

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I am trying to program the Bubble sort sorting algorithm in C for practice and revision, however, I have come across a few issues: I am trying to print every swap after every iteration in the array of 20 random numbers, however, the program seems to get rid of items which are bigger than the item before for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
int i, j, temp;
int SortData[20]= {20, 43, 90, 17, 2, 4, 67, 54, 0, 44, 78, 89, 21, 45, 72, 
88, 65, 100, 97, 25};
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");

 for (i=0; i<19; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<18;j++){
        if(SortData[j]>SortData[j+1])
        {
            temp = SortData[j];
            SortData[j]=SortData[j+1];
            SortData[j+1]=temp;
            printf("|%d", SortData[j]);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

And here is what happens when this code is ran:

```
|20|43|90|17|2|4|67|54|0|44|78|89|21|45|72|88|65|100|97|25|
|17|2|4|67|54|0|44|78|89|21|45|72|88|65|97
|17|2|4|54|0|44|21|45|72|88|65
|17|2|4|0|44|21|45|72|65
|2|4|0|21|45|65
|0|21|45|65
|0|21|65
|0|21
|0

Process returned 10 (0xA)   execution time : 3.072 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Moreover, I ran a few tests to check whether there was a bug in the sorting of the array or in the printing of it, here are the results from that test:

```
int i, j, temp;
int SortData[20]= {20, 43, 90, 17, 2, 4, 67, 54, 0, 44, 78, 89, 21, 45, 72, 
88, 65, 100, 97, 25};
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");

 for (i=0; i<19; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<18;j++){
        if(SortData[j]>SortData[j+1])
        {
            temp = SortData[j];
            SortData[j]=SortData[j+1];
            SortData[j+1]=temp;

        }

    }
    }
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        printf("|%d", SortData[i]);//Error here as 25 isn't sorted
    }
    printf("|");
    printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

The only change in this snippet from the above one is that the printing statement comes out of the nested for loop and printed using a separate for loop, this kind of works, as the numbers are sorted, but fro some reason 25 isn't:

```
|20|43|90|17|2|4|67|54|0|44|78|89|21|45|72|88|65|100|97|25|
|0|2|4|17|20|21|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97|100|25|
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So it turns out that there is an issue with the sorting and the printing. 
Could I please have some hints as to how print every iteration of the swap and get it to swap correctly?

UPDATE:

So I have incremented the loop counters by in the nested for loop and now it sorts out the array and shows every iteration. Here is what the changed code looks like:

```
int i, j, temp;
int SortData[20]= {20, 43, 90, 17, 2, 4, 67, 54, 0, 44, 78, 89, 21, 45, 72, 88, 65, 100, 97, 25};
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");

 for (i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<19;j++){
        if(SortData[j]>SortData[j+1])
        {
            temp = SortData[j];
            SortData[j]=SortData[j+1];
            SortData[j+1]=temp;

        }
            printf("|%d", SortData[j]);//Changed code
    }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //for (i=0; i<20; i++){
      //  printf("|%d", SortData[i]);//Error here as 25 isn't sorted
    //}
    printf("|");
    printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Now it does show every iteration, and sorts it, but for some reason the number 100 disappears from the array and thus it only sorts 19 items rather than 20:

```
|20|43|90|17|2|4|67|54|0|44|78|89|21|45|72|88|65|100|97|25|
|20|43|17|2|4|67|54|0|44|78|89|21|45|72|88|65|90|97|25
|20|17|2|4|43|54|0|44|67|78|21|45|72|88|65|89|90|25|97
|17|2|4|20|43|0|44|54|67|21|45|72|78|65|88|89|25|90|97
|2|4|17|20|0|43|44|54|21|45|67|72|65|78|88|25|89|90|97
|2|4|17|0|20|43|44|21|45|54|67|65|72|78|25|88|89|90|97
|2|4|0|17|20|43|21|44|45|54|65|67|72|25|78|88|89|90|97
|2|0|4|17|20|21|43|44|45|54|65|67|25|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|43|44|45|54|65|25|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|43|44|45|54|25|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|43|44|45|25|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|43|44|25|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|43|25|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|0|2|4|17|20|21|25|43|44|45|54|65|67|72|78|88|89|90|97
|

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why does 100 disappear?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text if ylou can post text.$

Comment: Apologies, will abstain in the future

Comment: Nothing prevents you from [edit]ing your question.

Comment: How does your code catch the last SortData[19] item? The variables `i` and `j` are never set to 19 and the same thing for even `i+1` or `j+1`

Comment: what is wrong on your first screen shot ? The number of permutations must decrease for every scan through your numbers.

Comment: I think you may take a look to a lot of useful links on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Bubble+sort+in+c

Comment: I suggest as a debugging technique, that you sort an array that contains the numbers 1 to 20.  That way you can quickly visually check that the array is in order, no values are duplicated, and no values were dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly, you did a little error:

```
int i, j, temp;
int SortData[20]= {20, 43, 90, 17, 2, 4, 67, 54, 0, 44, 78, 89, 21, 45, 72, 88, 65, 100, 97, 25};
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");
//before for(i=0; i<19; i++)
for (i=0; i<20; i++)// i < 20 or it will skip the last number
{
    //before for(j=0; j<18; j++)
    for(j=0;j<19;j++){
        if(SortData[j]>SortData[j+1])
        {
        temp = SortData[j];
        SortData[j]=SortData[j+1];
        SortData[j+1]=temp;
        }

    }
}
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");
return 0;
```

If you want to print every iteration of the bubble sorting, this is the code:

```
int i, j, temp, h;
int SortData[20]= {20, 43, 90, 17, 2, 4, 67, 54, 0, 44, 78, 89, 21, 45, 72, 88, 65, 100, 97, 25};
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");

for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<19;j++){
        if(SortData[j]>SortData[j+1])
        {
            temp = SortData[j];
            SortData[j]=SortData[j+1];
            SortData[j+1]=temp;
            for (h=0; h<20; h++)
            {
                printf("|%d", SortData[h]);
            }
            printf("|");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, but what about printing every swap/iteration

Comment: Edit the answer to include the print on every iteration. If my answer satisfies you, please mark it

Answer (score 1):

on line 11 of that code snippet you put in, you're only using the first 19 records for sorting. Set this code to 20 and solve.

I comment the line where i fix.

Tip: Possibly you are starting out in software development and for this type of case it would be interesting to learn how to use a debug.

```
int i, j, temp;
int SortData[20]= {20, 43, 90, 17, 2, 4, 67, 54, 0, 44, 78, 89, 21, 45, 72, 
88, 65, 100, 97, 25};
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("|%d", SortData[i]);
}
printf("|");
printf("\n");

// before > for (i=0; i<19; i++)
 for (i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
// before > for(j=0;j<18;j++){
    for(j=0;j<19;j++){
        if(SortData[j]>SortData[j+1])
        {
            temp = SortData[j];
            SortData[j]=SortData[j+1];
            SortData[j+1]=temp;

        }

    }
    }
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        printf("|%d", SortData[i]);//Error here as 25 isn't sorted
    }
    printf("|");
    printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: did you copy/paste the same code of the post without changing anything?
I highly suggest you to fix the problem in the code you are posting or it's better to just leave a comment!

Comment: Thanks for comment, I'm new on StackOverflow. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow then! I highly suggest you to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to contribute better next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're just skipping the last number , when you are using for loop. Run your for loop for i<20 instead of i<19 because it is skipping the last number while sorting.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Unfortunately this isn't an answer but a comment, please delete it and post it as a comment!

Comment: You're just skipping the last number , when you are using for loop. Run your for loop for i<20 instead of i<19 because it is skipping the last number while sorting.